# Propogating Strapi to Astro via Vercel

Tags: vercel, astrojs

A couple of days ago, I updated my frontend repo and redeployed. It gave me the impression that I had fixed an issue where changes in the strapi CMS weren't being displayed in the frontend.

However, two days later, and I'm trying to edit and create again in Strapi and this time without redeploying the frontend, but now it isn't updating the content displayed on the site.

Currently in the src folder we have a file called data.js which fetches all the Strapi data. The astro files then import this data and this is how it's propogated.

I'm trying to understand why the changes were reflected after the Vercel deployment a couple of days ago and why no Vercel redeploy means the data isn't updated.

The Strapi changes are being made succesfully inside the PostgreSQL database so I don't believe it's a problem with Strapi or the database.

I'm wondering if it's to do with the way fetching takes place in Astro?

```
src
  api
    cms.ts
  data.js
  ...
```

data.js sample

```js
import { fetchAllCollections } from "./api/cms";

const allCollections = await fetchAllCollections();
const { services, members, testimonials, clients } = allCollections;

export const servicesData = services || {
  services: [
    {
      title: "Research and Analytics",
    // ...
    }
]
```

cms.ts

```
export const COLLECTIONS = {
  SERVICES: "services",
  TEAM_MEMBERS: "members",
  CLIENTS: "clients",
  TESTIMONIALS: "testimonials",
};

const formatCollection = (collection) => {
  return collection.map((entry) => entry.attributes);
};

const fetchCollection = async (
  endpoint,
  domain = "correct-endpoint"
) => {
  const rawCollection = await fetch(domain + endpoint + "?populate=*").then(
    (res) => res.json()
  );
  return formatCollection(rawCollection.data);
};

export const fetchAllCollections = async () => {
  try {
    const services = await fetchCollection(COLLECTIONS.SERVICES);
    // ...
    return { services, clients, testimonials, members };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.msg);
  }
};
```

Comment: Astro is static by default. Have you added the [Vercel SSR adapter](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/deploy/vercel/#adapter-for-ssr) and set `output` to `server` in your Astro config to enable SSR?

Comment: Thanks, yes, I'm on my way down that path as it looks like the right solution! Just bumped into dependency issues which is slowing me down though. Thanks for your help so far. I'll be happy to update you and mark your comment as a solution when I've confirmed it.

Answer (score 0):

The first half of the answer is Otterlords suggestion to output SSR and use the Vercel SSR Adaptor. I noticed that the network response showed the data arrived instantly, however Vercel didn't render the data into HTML nodes until after each Vercel Deployment. The solution to keep the website and the CMS in sync was to use a webhook.

It's really straight forward. Here are the links I found helpful.

https://strapi.io/blog/webhooks

https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/cms/strapi/#rebuild-on-changes

https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/deploy-hooks